# How get session data in magento block?

Tags: magento, session

I am setting Magento session but unable to get it in my block.

I have controller where session data is save into `LB_Session`.

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setLB_Session(serialize($_SESSION['LB_Session']));
```

I am  getting this into controller.

But when I try to get it in block its not working.

I am calling block on add product to cart page which is called as per below

```
<catalog_product_view>
<reference name="product.info.addtocart">
<block type="lb/lbblock" name="lbregistration_button_lbblock" template="lb/lbregistration_button.phtml" />
<reference name="content" >
<block type="lb/lbblock" name="lbregistration_popup_lbblock" template="lb/lbregistration_popup.phtml" />
</reference>
</reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t think `setLB_Session()` is a [valid setter name](http://www.coolryan.com/magento/2012/04/06/magic-methods-inside-magento/) unless you defined that method on the `customer/session` model yourself. It should be something like `setLbSession()` and then you can retrieve it elsewhere in the application with `getLbSession()`.

Comment: But I am not getting the proper variable value from session class when I set any session variable value from my custom extension which is only accessible when i call any page from the same extension indexController but I need my session data throughout the mangeto pages. Please can tell me is there any difference in magento application session and custom extension session?

Comment: @user3205412 - Maybe you should try `core/session` instead?

Comment: Yes I had tried `core/session` but it does not work for me... But my problem was solve by adding `start_session` in index.php file at root, can you please tell me how to start session in magento by default because I am not sure the way I had done using index.php is it proper or not. after all I am developing my own extension so how can I change index.php at root. Thanks for your reply...

Comment: @user3205412 - It’s possible you are just trying to use the session too early. I would definitely advise against going straight into it from `index.php`. @alan-storm [has a nice write up about this](http://alanstorm.com/magento_sessions_early) that you should check out.

Comment: thank you very much... for your help and the above link which you have given its very useful to resolve my problem. I used `controller_front_init_before` event to initialize session on every page load and it works. only the think which I want to mention here is- "only global-area observers will be able to observe this event."